# angular-schema-form doesn't build and no error

Tags: angular-schema-form

I'm trying to build a simple test app with angular-schema-form with no success.

```
{
  "name": "schema form test",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.x",
    "angular-route": "1.3.x",
    "angular-schema-form": "0.7.3",
    "tv4": "~1.0.15",
    "angular-sanitize": ">= 1.2",
    "objectpath": "~1.0.4",
    "jquery": "~2.1.x",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.x"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.3.x"
  }
}
```

Then the code is actually a copy-paste of example from https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form and it doesn't work. Does anybody see any problems with versions above?

Answer (score 1):

Actually nothing wrong with versions here. It's just stupid me, who didn't put 'schemaForm' in requires when calling angular.module.